# Поместить Particle System за Sprite Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

кто нибудь знает как поместить Particle System за Sprite?

Sprite Renderer не использую, у меня изначально был Empty Object куда я навесил Image, Animation и Event Trigger. Сверху над объектом у меня весит Particle System и идёт вниз что-то вроде дождя из другого спрайта.

Проблема в том что Particle System идёт поверх этого объекта (да и не только, он идёт поверх всех объектов), мне нужно это исправить, ну конечно нужно ещё чтобы он не шёл за background'ом

Также пытался играться с этим:

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingOrder = 0;
```

но мне не помогло, возможно не правильно использовал (Навесил новый скрипт на Particle и в Start() добавил эту строку).

Comment: По умолчанию частицы имеют полупрозрачный (transparent) шейдер, который рисуется после всех непрозрачных шейдеров, какой бы порядок отрисовки вы бы не ставили.

Comment: В редакторе юнити у системы частиц вкладку Renderer посмотрите там настраивается слой